# ArangoDB - how to implement a custom recommendation engine using graph?

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

Lets say we have a database of food items such as:

```
item1 = {name: 'item1', tags: ['mexican', 'spicy']};
item2 = {name: 'item2', tags: ['sweet', 'chocolate', 'nuts']};
item3 = {name: 'item3', tags: ['sweet', 'vanilla', 'cold']};
```

And we have a user looking for food recommendations, where they indicate their preference weight for some tags:

```
foodPref = {sweet: 4, chocolate: 11}
```

Now we need to calculate how well each item scores and recommend the best items:

```
item1 score = 0 (doesn't contain any of the tags user is looking for)
item2 score = 4 (contains the tag 'sweet')
item3 score = 15 (contains the tag 'sweet' and 'chocolate')
```

I have modeled the problem as a graph:[image: sample graph]

What's the correct way to get the recommendations -- a custom traversal object or just filter and count using AQL or just implement it in Foxx (javascript layer)?

Also, can you help out with a sample implementation for the methods you suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm doing a food recommendation engine with arangodb, want to get in touch and talk about that?

Comment: Sure! Please email me at stalemett on gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets create the collections and their contents the way you specified them. We will add a second user.

```
db._create("user")
db._create("tags")
db._create("dishes")

db.user.save({_key: 'user1'})
db.user.save({_key: 'user2'})

db.tags.save({_key: 'sweet'})
db.tags.save({_key: 'chocolate'})
db.tags.save({_key: 'vanilla'})
db.tags.save({_key: 'spicy'})

db.dishes.save({_key: 'item1'})
db.dishes.save({_key: 'item2'})
db.dishes.save({_key: 'item3'})
```

Now lets create the edge collections with their edges:

```
db._createEdgeCollection("userPreferences")
db._createEdgeCollection("dishTags")

db.userPreferences.save("user/user1", "tags/sweet", {score: 4})
db.userPreferences.save("user/user1", "tags/chocolate", {score: 11})
db.userPreferences.save("user/user2", "tags/sweet", {score: 27})
db.userPreferences.save("user/user2", "tags/vanilla", {score: 7})

db.dishTags.save("tags/sweet", "dishes/item2", {score: 4});
db.dishTags.save("tags/sweet", "dishes/item3", {score: 7})
db.dishTags.save("tags/chocolate", "dishes/item2", {score: 2})
db.dishTags.save("tags/vanilla", "dishes/item3", {score: 3})
db.dishTags.save("tags/spicy", "dishes/item1", {score: 666})
```

Our relations are like this:

```
user-[userPreferences]->tags-[dishTags]->dishes
```

finding out what `user1` likes can be done with this query:

```
FOR v, e IN 1..2 OUTBOUND "user/user1" userPreferences, dishTags
  RETURN {item: v, connection: e}
```

if you now want to find all dishes that `user1` likes best:

```
FOR v, e IN 2..2 OUTBOUND "user/user1" userPreferences, dishTags 
  FILTER e.score > 4 RETURN v
```

We filter for the `score` attribute.

Now we want to find another user that has the same preferences as `user1` does:

```
FOR v, e IN 2..2 ANY "user/user1" userPreferences RETURN v
```

We go into `ANY` direction (forward and backward), but only are interested in the `userPreferences` edge collection, else 2..2 would also give use dishes. The way we do it now. we go back into the user collections to find users with similar preferences.

Whether or not creating a Foxx-service is a good option depends on personal preferences. Foxx is great if you want to combine & filter results on the server side, so client communication is less. You can also use it if you like to put your Application rather on top of microservices than on db-queries. Your application may then stay free of database specific code - it only [operates with the microservice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) as its backend. There may be usecases where Foxx

In general, there is no "correct" way - there are different ways which you may prefer above others because of performance, code cleanness, scalability, etc.